# How to get a variable from a parameter function outside his class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating an GUI interface for my own project in python with tkinter library.

On one frame i setted an tk.Entry for me to write some text.
I want to use this information in the next Frame (let's say in a tk.Label to be simple)
But i can't reach the information, seems to be because the two function belong to differents class.

Tried to make private_key global but seems to overwrite in the definition.
Tried to return private_key but i still can't access it because i can't call the parameter in the next class.
Tried to use the function again in the next class, same problem.
Tried to set the label in the PVK class, doesn't seems to work either

```py
from tkinter import *

# type and size of font
LARGE_FONT = ('MS Serif', 15)
# white writing color
FRONT_COLOR = '#ffffff'
# dark_gray background color
BACKGROUND_COLOR = '#272727'


class Bobby(Tk):

    # Used each time the function is called
    def __init__(self):
        # init tkinter
        Tk.__init__(self)

        Tk.iconbitmap(self, default='bobby.ico')
        Tk.wm_title(self, "Bobby")
        Tk.geometry(self, '500x200')

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for f in (PVK, Display):

            frame = f(container, self)

            self.frames[f] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)

        self.show_frame(Welcome)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class PVK(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)
        here = Label(self, text="here", font=LARGE_FONT, background=BACKGROUND_COLOR, fg=FRONT_COLOR)
        here.grid()
        self.pvk = Entry(self, show=" ")
        self.pvk.bind('<Return>', self.check)
        self.pvk.grid()

    def check(self, event):
        private_key = int(self.pvk.get()), 11413
        bobby.show_frame(Display)
        return private_key

class Display(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

        #want to display it here
        Label(self, text=str(PVK.private_key)).grid()


bobby = Bobby()
bobby.mainloop()
```

My expect is to display the label with the text in it which would mean i can use the variable.
I currently get the error that private_key isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass `controller` into the `__init__()` of `Display`, then you could find the instance of the `PVK` class:

```
class PVK(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        # stuff omitted

    def check(self, event):
        self.private_key = int(self.pvk.get()), 11413  # note self.private_key
        bobby.show_frame(Display)

class Display(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.configure(background=BACKGROUND_COLOR)

        #want to display it here
        private_key = controller.frames[PVK].private_key
        Label(self, text=str(private_key)).grid()
```

There will be other ways to access `private_key`, eg PVK could write it back to the controller: `self.controller.private_key = private_key` etc

Comment: Both your solution made the same error for me :
"    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'self'"
The debug tell me he don't like the line "private_key = controller.self.frames[PVK].private_key".
On the first way i also got a warning at "self.private_key = int(self.pvk.get()), 11413"
It say it detects instance attribute definition outside __init__ method :/
Not sure what to do

Comment: Sorry, `controller.self` is a mistake. Should be `controller.frames[PVK].private_key`

Comment: To fix the warning, you can add `self.private_key = None` to `__init__()` of `PVK`

Comment: Both of your answer were actually needed. The code run without error but i don't get the resulst i was seeking for.
In my Label in the class display, the text is setted to "None" as initialised in my ```__init__()``` of PVK. I also tried to add a return at my check function but didn't help

Comment: Oh, I see. That `Label` is created in the `__init__()` of `Display` and not updated later on.

Comment: Never used update for the moment so i tried some stuff.
I tried to set ```controller.frames[PVK].private_key``` as a ```Stringvar()``` and to update my Display with ```Display.update_idletasks(self)``` but my Label still write "none". That was my best attempt so far. Going to keep searching for a way.

Comment: You need to write an `update()` method for your `Frame`s which `Bobby` calls before calling `tkraise()`. The `update()` can refresh the text in the `Label`.